# Selenium WebDriverWait throwing exception

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm trying to wait until a element is present before continuing, however with the method I'm currently using it's throwing element does not exist, even before timeout has ended.

Example usage:

```
 using OpenQA.Selenium;
 using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
 using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

 private static WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)); // inside parent class (not method)

 //public static void Method1()

 wait.Until(driver => driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[foo=bar]")));
```

which should then wait 30 seconds or until element is present, but it instantly throws element not found exception...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm) class in general and [ElementExists()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_ElementExists.htm) function in particular, suggested code:

```
https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_ElementExists.htm
```

Example code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement element  = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("[foo=bar]")));
```

Example output:

[image]

More information:

- [Explicit Waits](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits)
- [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/)

Comment: I ended up using this solution, this was what I initially tried, but ExpectedConditions was deprecated by Support.UI, you now have to install a nuget package called `SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers'